# Trying to find the max number in a python array?

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a python program that will print me a random numbers array 1 thur 100, and also print out the max value of the array. This is what I have so far:

```
import random
import timeit
print [random.randint(0,100) for r in xrange(10)]
print "Max number in array is",
```

Comment: Have you looked at, let's say, the `max` function?

Comment: sorry I'm a novice with Python, I thought I was using the max function correctly, I was wrong.

Comment: @ChrisSanders If you don't use it at all, you definitely don't use it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Save the random numbers in a variable, `data`. Then take the [max](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max) with `max(data)`.

```
data = [random.randint(0,100) for r in xrange(10)]
print(data)
print("Max number in array is {}".format(max(data)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to store the array as generated in a variable, and just use `max` on it to get the maximum value;

```
import random
import timeit
my_array = [random.randint(0,100) for r in xrange(10)]
print my_array
print "Max number in array is", max(my_array)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import random
rand_ar = [random.randint(1,100) for r in xrange(10)] # randint(0,100) includes 0 also.
print rand_ar
print "Max number in array is %i" % max(rand_ar)
```